# Eigenfunctions of the integral kernel $1/(x^2 + x'^2)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, eigenvector, integral-kernel

My question seems elementary, yet I could not find the solution after working on and searching for several days...
I'd like to find the eigenfunctions of a simple integral kernel:
\begin{equation}
\lambda f_\lambda(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{d x'}{x^2 +x'^2} f_\lambda(x')
\end{equation}
There is an obvious scaling property
\begin{equation}
f_{\lambda'}(x)=f_\lambda(x \lambda/\lambda'),
\end{equation}
so it suffices to find an eigenfunction at a certain $\lambda$.

It looks like the theory of complex functions may be of help here, and $f(x)$ can be analytically continued to the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} z >0$, from the line $\operatorname{Im}z =0$, $\operatorname{Re}z >0$. One can thus derive an equation relating the values of $f(z)$ at  this line and the line $\operatorname{Im}(z)=0$,
\begin{equation}
\lambda \left(f(-i x+ \delta) - f(i x + \delta) \right) = \frac{i}{2 x} f(x);
\end{equation}
$x>0$, $\delta>0, \delta \to 0$. However, I am not able to guess the solution of this equation.

With some sweat, I can find asymptotic approximations at $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$ but I'd like the whole function... Come on, that must be a well-known one :)

**Update:**

Just to give the concrete expressions. Inspecting the equation for the analytical continuation, I've obtained the asymptotic expression for $f(x)$ at small $x$ ($\lambda = 1/2)$,
\begin{equation}
f(x) \propto x^{-1/2} \cos\left(\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\pi} + O(1)\right),
\end{equation}

and at big $x$:
\begin{equation}
f(x) \propto \frac{1}{x^2} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{4\lambda x} + \frac{\ln(\lambda x)}{8 \pi (\lambda x)^2}\right) + O(x^{-4}) 
\end{equation}

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an eigenfunction? What space should it lie in? Your operator is not obviously bounded on one of the common spaces (at least this is what it looks like to me). An unbounded (or just non-compact) operator need not have any eigenfunctions. For example, if $(Tf)(x)=\int_0^{\infty} f(t)\, dt$, then $Tf=\lambda f$ formally seems to demand that $f$ is constant, but of course this isn't working.

Comment: An eigenfunction, in my mind, is the solution of either equation that does not diverge upon $x \to \infty$. It is a member of Hilbert space of normalizable ($\int_0^\infty f^2(x) dx < {\rm const}$ real functions defined at $(0, \infty)$. I am sure the solution exists :)

Comment: The numerics have to be done with care. It is clear that the spectrum is unbounded owing to the scaling property mentioned. The eigenfunction has infinite number of zeros in the proximity of $x=0$, that is, strongly non-analytical at $x=0$. A reasonable numerical scheme should account for this.

Comment: crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4762166/87355

Comment: @ChristianRemling That is if you can swap the order of integration in $\iint \frac{f(x)g(y)}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$, but the singularity at $0$ is too strong for that, so I do not see how to formally rule an $L^2$ eigenfunction out this way.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I just said that the usual proof of the orthogonality of the eigenfunctions of a symmetric operator corresponding to different eigenvalues seems to fail miserably because the identity $(Af,g)=(f,Ag)$ cannot be easily established even if both sides make sense, and I didn't know how one could possibly rescue it. Note that the OP invokes a "formal" definition of the eigenfunction that may have nothing to do with self-adjoint extensions or spectral theorem as far as I can see it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ChristianRemling : I've updated the question giving the concrete asymptotic expressions, perhaps this would make the discussion more concrete :)

Comment: @YuliNazarov Well, your asymptotic behavior at $0$ certainly places the function outside of $L^2$, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Hmmm... What part of the claims you make does not apply to the operator $i\frac d{dx}$ on $(0,1)$ with the initial domain $C^1_c(0,1)$? Obviously, we have any $e^{ax}$ as a formal eigenfunction there.

Comment: @fedja: Yes, I know this. As I wrote earlier, I never claimed to have proved anything. My initial feeling at least was that the integral operator is different from the $iD$ example because one would expect domains of self-adjoint extensions to be defined in terms of the asymptotic behavior of $f\in L^2$ as $x\to 0$ (or maybe not?), and then such domains might well be invariant under $f(x)\mapsto f(qx)$.

Comment: @fedja: One difference to $iD$ is that $0\in\sigma(S)$ for our operator for any self-adjoint realization $S$ (because even $T^*$ doesn't map onto $L^2$), and purely discrete spectrum looks unlikely here (though again, this isn't proved).

Comment: Here are two not very directly relevant but perhaps mildly interesting facts I just found: (1) The operator with kernel $1/(x+t)$ on $L^2(0,\infty)$ has purely absolutely continuous spectrum; (2) (von Neumann) A normal operator $T$ (on $L^2(0,\infty)$, say) is unitarily equivalent to a Carleman operator if and only if $0\in\sigma_{\textrm{ess}}(T)$.

Comment: @fedja: Regarding your earlier comment, on the asymptotic formula, if the $O(1)$ inside the cosine tries really hard, then even $f\equiv 0$ is consistent with the asymptotics given.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Of course, you are perfectly right here :lol: I also have no idea whether *any* reasonable eigenfunction exists in this setting and somehow it seems rather shameful that I still cannot figure it out. :-(

Comment: @fedja: Or it would be nice to just know the deficiency index of the symmetric operator, but that perversely leads to the same problem (with $\lambda=i$).

Comment: To answer _"Come on, that must be a well-known one :)"_ : it is not in Polyanin and Manzhirov's massive "Handbook of Integral Equations" --- they solve $f(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{-p}K(x/t)f(t)\,dt$ for $p=1$ and arbitrary kernel $K$, but here $p=2$.

Comment: Substitution $x=e^t, F(t)=f(e^t)$ turn is into a convolution $\lambda e^t F(t) = (2\pi)^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d t' F(t')/[2\cosh(t-t')]$, but I was unable to make any progress in either "time" or "frequency" domain.

Comment: Thank you, @Michał Jan , know this, in principle, with this one can compute asymptotes at $t \to \pm \infty$ but the analytical continuation equation is more efficient in this respect ...

Comment: @CristianRemling, I must apologize for a stupid lapse of tongue, the functions $f_\lambda(x)$ are not normalizable, belong to $L^1$ rather then to $L^2$, the orthogonality relation is supposed to be like $\int_0^\infty dx f_\lambda(x) f_{\lambda'}(x) = \delta(\lambda-\lambda')$

Comment: Follow-up on the last comment by @CarloBeenakker. For $p=1$, the [unitary Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#As_an_isometry_on_L2_spaces) diagonalizes such convolution operators, making it clear why they would have continuous spectrum. In this case, the Mellin transform formally turns the eigenproblem into $\lambda \hat{f}(s-i) = \hat{K}(s) \hat{f}(s)$. Yes, the shift of $\hat{f}(s)$ is in the imaginary direction, so it would only be defined on a domain of sufficiently nice vectors. I don't see any easy conditions on $\lambda$ under which the resolvent exists.

Comment: If it helps anyone, the Mellin transform of the kernel is explicitly computable: $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x} x^t \frac{x}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi t}{2})}$.

Comment: It is funny that the similar kernel $1/\max(x^2,y^2)$ is perfectly tractable and the corresponding "eigenfunction" solves a certain linear second order ODE with polynomial coefficients, which allows one to use the WKB asymptotics near $0$ and the expansion into the series in $1/x$ near $\infty$, but the explicit form is, obviously, out of question even then. Moreover, near $0$ the oscillation there is much faster than that in Yuli's asymptorics, which makes one suspect that the smooth case may be drastically different in some respects.